# Convert the code in swift 3

Tags: swift3

```
let string = "/Date(1268123281843)/"
if let startRange = string.rangeOfString("("),endRange = string.rangeOfString(")") {
  let substring = string[startRange.endIndex..<endRange.startIndex]
  print(substring)
}
```

Note: I need this code in swift 3. Kindly help me out. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "i need code in swift 3"

Comment: I did this code in swift 2.2 . Its working fine. But It's not working in swift 3.

Comment: can you see the whole code?

Comment: Can You see the whole code? @NazmulHasan

Comment: did you try it to convert swift ? what is the issue ?

Comment: I am using Xcode8 and swift3 version. I use the same code on Xcode7.3. It's working fine. But In Xcode 8 , It's showing error. I need the same  code in swift 3. @NazmulHasan

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: if let startRange = string.rangeOfString("("),endRange = string.rangeOfString(")") { ---------> In this Line after the , It asking for one more let  for endRange in Xcode8. But It's not asking in Xcode 7.3.

Comment: If you have Xcode8 you can check it the error. Don't know how to explain here. @NazmulHasan

Answer (score 1):

rangeOfString should be contains.
Check this artile. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3

```
let startRange = string.contains("(")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in xcode 8 (Swift 3):

```
extension String {
  func subString(from leftCharacter: String, to rightCharacter: String) -> String? {
    guard leftCharacter.characters.count > 0 && rightCharacter.characters.count > 0 else {
      return nil
    }

    let left = Character(leftCharacter)
    let right = Character(rightCharacter)

    let leftIndex = string.characters.index(of: left)
    let rightIndex = string.characters.index(of: right)

    if let leftIndex = leftIndex, let _ = rightIndex {
      string.removeSubrange(string.startIndex...leftIndex)
      if let rightIndex = string.characters.index(of: right) {
        string.removeSubrange(rightIndex..<string.endIndex)
        return string
      }

      return nil
    }

    return nil
  }
}
```

---

```
var string = "/Date(1268123281843)/"

let leftCharacter = "("
let rightCharacter = ")"

if let subtractedString = string.subString(from: leftCharacter, to: rightCharacter) {
  print(subtractedString) //1268123281843
}
```